# Access denied issue while recording Jmeter script

Tags: file, jmeter

I am getting file not found exception while start recording..Also, I am not able to find out the RootCA certificate in the JMeter installable folder.

Comment: Provide some more info, read it first [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when I click on start, getting "java .io. filenot found exception: proxy server.jks " (Access is denied). how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

As per [TestRecording210](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210) JMeter Wiki Page it happens when user, you run JMeter under, doesn't have write access to JMeter's "bin" folder:

> Another cause of errors is where the JMeter bin directory is not writable, as JMeter defaults to creating the keystore in the bin directory. For example
>
> Could not create script recording proxy - see log for details: Command :'"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool" -genkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_ DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: user, C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted) -keypass {redacted) -validity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1
>   keytool error: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: proxyserver.jks (Access is denied)**
>
> The last line shows the cause.
>
> The cure is to tell JMeter where to create the keystore, by defining the property

```
proxy.cert.directory
```

In order to do it add the next line to *user.properties* file (it is located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
proxy.cert.directory=/some/folder/you/have/write/access
```

And on the next JMeter restart it should start working.

You can also consider an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - "SmartJMX" mode available via [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service. In that case you won't have to worry about proxy servers, certificates, etc. Moreover it will even perform automatic correlation so you will be able to safe some time usually required to handle dynamic parameters.

Comment: am not able to add above said line in the user, properties file. Getting message as 'Access denied'. I am holding admin rights for my laptop...Please help

Comment: had the same issue as windows user. Realised that after installing (unpacking) JMeter, the access rights have not been set for all users. So corrected this. I installed JMETER in "C:\Program Files\Apache JMeter". Right click on that folder allows to modifiy the properties. Under Security give the "Users" full access. JMeter is now able to save the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the options provided across many answers and was not able to fix this. The actual problem is the user that tyring to run jmeter does not have access to the required folders. One way of fixing this is to provide necessary access to the folder or make it very open for any one to read or write.

cd to /usr/local/Cellar
Then run the command "sudo chmod -R 777 jmeter/"

Just be careful 777 makes the entire folder structure very open for anyone to read or write into it

Answer (score 0):

RootCA certificate will be generated only after running the script by adding the HTTP(s) test script Recorder.

Follow the following steps:

1. Go to `Jmeter` bin folder and run `jmeter.bat` file
2. Now add the thread group then add go to Logic Controller and add recording controller
3. Add HTTP(s) test script recorder
4. Now, run the script
5. Go to bin folder
6. Observe `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA` certificate is created.