# Is there a reason I'm not able to start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Tags: jmeter, proxy-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFziH.png)

I do not have workbench on Apache 5.3 and due to which I don't have HTTP Proxy Server. I used the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. Started Chrome and manually configured the proxy settings. Settings => Advanced => Network => Manual Proxy:localhost and port as 8080(same as configured on the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S5pH.png)But when I click on Start button on the recorder, Im getting the below error. Can someone please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174781/access-denied-issue-while-recording-jmeter-script

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that JMeter is not able to generate `proxyserver.jks` file (Java keystore to keep [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate allowing JMeter to intercept and decrypt SSL traffic) because it doesn't have read/write access to the folder where you launch JMeter from.

The solutions are in:

1. Run JMeter [as administrator](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/run-as-admin), administrators have full control over all folders
2. Change [`proxy.cert.directory` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert) to some folder where your user has access rights
3. If for some reason you cannot go for steps 1 and/or 2 you should be able to record your test scenario using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)